# Groovy constructor giving compile error 'due to hash collision" in constructors

Tags: groovy, constructor

I am trying to add a constructor to a Groovy class, but adding a second method as a constructor i am getting a compile error..

> Unable to compile class ... due to hash collision in constructors

```
class BaseException extends RuntimeException {

private Integer status
private String message
private Long timestap
private List<ErrorMessage> errors

    BaseException(Integer status, String message, List<ErrorMessage> errorMessageList) {
        this.status = status
        this.message = message
        this.timestap = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.errors = errorMessageList
    }

    // ---
    // adding the method below gives a compile error
    // ---
    BaseException(Integer status, String message, List<ErrorCode> errorCodeList) {
        this.status = status
        this.message = message
        this.timestap = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.errors = []
        errorCodeList.each { error ->
            this.errors.add(new ErrorMessage(error.code, error.description))
        }
    }
    .. code emitted
}
```

Any hint what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have two constructors or methods with the same signature once generics are removed due to erasure. Same goes for Java. If you really really need this, it's usual to have two static factory method with different names and a less accessible constructor that handles both cases

Comment: You should put that comment in an answer.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr done... I'll come up with an example when I get to a computer ;-) phones are rubbish for writing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two constructors or methods with the same signature once generics are removed due to erasure.

Same goes for Java.

If you really really need this, it's usual to have two static factory method with different names and a less accessible constructor that handles both cases